# How to evenly delete a specific number of rows from a list?

Tags: arrays, list

I want to write the logic to delete a specific number of rows from a list and I want to select the rows for deletion as evenly as possible. This is easy when I want to delete 25% or 50% from a list, I simply write the logic to delete every 4th or 2nd row respectively. However, how could I write the logic to allow me to delete a number that doesn't divide as cleanly and still keep it spaced out as evenly as possible?

For example, out of a list of 1000 how would I determine which rows to delete in order to delete say 40% of them as evenly as possible? I know I would sometimes need to delete every third row (33%) and sometimes every second row (50%) but I haven't come up with the routine to determine which rows to delete in order to keep it as even as possible throughout the list.

Comment: Can you post an algorithm or pseudocode of what you've come up with so far ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to work out first how many records you need to go through before you delete one - this must be a floating point number. For example:

```
percentage = 37.0
lineCount = 912.0
deleteEveryN = 100.0 / percentage    # ~2.702 lines
```

Then, you just count the lines, deleting every relevant one. By using floating point, you can avoid the situation where you only delete every `N` lines - sometimes it may be `N-1` or `N+1`, depending on the values.

```
countToNextDeletion = deleteEveryN / 2
foreach line:
    countToNextDeletion = countToNextDeletion - 1.0
    if countToNextDeletion <= 0.0:
        delete line
        countToNextDeletion = countToNextDeletion + deleteEveryN
```

The reason we initialise `countToNextDeletion` to *half* the line count is to balance up the two ends as much as possible (make the deletions symmetrical around the midpoint). This is a trick I learned with line drawing algorithms (from Bresenham, from memory). Otherwise you may not delete as much as you expect because you get only 97% through the final group without reaching the deletion point.

You can see this algorithm in action with the following Python program:

```
percentage = 37
lineCount = 97
deleteEveryN = 100.0 / percentage
print "Delete every %f" % deleteEveryN

delCount = 0
countToNextDeletion = deleteEveryN / 2
for n in range (lineCount):
    countToNextDeletion = countToNextDeletion - 1.0
    if countToNextDeletion <= 0.0:
        print "Deleting %d" % n
        delCount = delCount + 1
        countToNextDeletion = countToNextDeletion + deleteEveryN

print "Deleted %d/%d (%f%%)" % (delCount, lineCount, delCount*100.0/lineCount)
```

The output of this is (output modified slightly to conserve vertical space):

```
pax> python testprog.py
Delete every 2.702703
Deleting 1
Deleting 4
Deleting 6
Deleting 9
Deleting 12
Deleting 14
Deleting 17
Deleting 20
Deleting 22
Deleting 25, 28, 31, 33, 36, 39, 41, 44, 47, 49, 52, 55, 58
Deleting 60, 63, 66, 68, 71, 74, 77, 79, 82, 85, 87, 90, 93
Deleting 95
Deleted 36/97 (37.113402%)
```

You can see there that it sometimes deletes every second line and sometimes every third, depending on the threshold value (more threes than twos since the `everyN` value is `2.7ish`).

The final line also shows that this is the best match for the given data:

```
linesDeleted/lineCount  percentage  deltaPercentage (from 37)
======================  ==========  =========================
                 35/97  36.0824742      0.9175258
                 36/97  37.1134021      0.1134021 <== closest
                 37/97  38.1443299      1.1443299
```

---

Just to show how it works for the first few iterations, `countToNextDeletion` is initially set to `2.7027027 / 2` or `1.3513514`. For the first line `0`, we add `1` to get `2.3513514` but that doesn't exceed the threshold.

Second line `1`, we add `1` to get `3.3513514` which *is* above the threshold so we delete the line and subtract the threshold to get `0.6486487`.

Then it takes *another* three lines to push us above the threshold to `3.6486487` at which point we delete the line `4` and subtract the threshold to get `0.945946`.

That only takes another *two* lines from there to reach `2.945946`, above the threshold so we delete `6` and subtract the threshold to get `0.2432433`.

So basically, you are remembering with great detail (floating point) where you are through the list but only deleting on integer boundaries.